# What causes the 'Duplicate class' error in Singular setup for Flutter apps, and how to fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, analytics, singular

Implementing Singular in Flutter application and getting sdk setup error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.actions.ReserveIntents found in modules jetified-play-services-6.5.87-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
```

https://support.singular.net/hc/en-us/articles/4408894547227-Singular-SDK-Integration-for-Flutter

Following this link to set up Singular and it showing me error for Android duplicate class

app/build.gradle:

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.tasks_app"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-

build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0+'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

From the documentation I followed the steps but Firebase class is clashing I don't understand much as I am first time trying to implement this type of sdk for analytics purpose and I want to learn about Singular

Comment: Can you add your gradle file over here with dependencies you added so we can check issue

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani I added the gradle file

Comment: Can you comment this dependecy and try again ```implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'``` as it is conflicting with ```play-services-ads-identifier```

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani Yes it works but play-service is required if check singular documentation then if I remove play-service-ads then also it gives me same error